# How to set a reminder to change the passwords in 45 days on linux and unix machines?

Tags: linux, unix

Please tell me how to set a remainder to change the passwords for every 45 days on linux and unix machines.

Thanks,
Srihari

Comment: Should be over at unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [chage command in Linux](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_chage.htm).

Comment: Hi Anubhava can you please provide one example with change command and eloborate,I aleardy used passwd command for changing the password can I use the same for get warning messages for password expiry.

Comment: @srihari: Here are some examples of change command: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/chage-linux-password-expiration-and-aging/

Answer (score 2):

Also look at the -w and -x of the passwd command - at least on linux, not sure about other platforms.

Comment: Works in Solaris